# How to read decimals form jsonobjects in java?

Tags: java, json, http, request, decimal

How do I read decimal values from JSONObject in java?

I have the "time" key with value as a decimal from python's Decimal module. How can I read this in java? say the json containing it is called request_json, do i get the value with

request_json.getDouble("time")?

Comment: Depends on which library you use to parse json

Comment: I am using the org.json.JSONObject library. getDouble is one of the methods for JSONObjects.

Comment: So ```request_json.getDouble("time")``` is not working?

Comment: Decimals are not doubles though.

Comment: try request_json.get("time")

Answer (score 0):

```
String res = request_json.getString("time");
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(res);
```